# Object lost in the space of 3d enviroment

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing, materials

[image]

I had problems with the zoom, maybe because the scale of the object. I zoomed in and disapear, then out and i lost it, I tried to press the Numpad, but nothing

Comment: Go to View > Frame All

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the lost object  in the outliner, move the cursor to the 3D viewport and press <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> (numpad period). To zoom the view to the selected object.